# How can I present the date on an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, date

I have the following code where I'd like my date to be presented via the HTML page:

```
<html>
    <p>Today's Date:</p><text id = "dateHere"></text>
</html>
```

And JavaScript to retrieve the date to present onto the webpage:

```
function theDate() {
var date = new Date();
var months = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
var currentDate = date.getDate();
var month = months[date.getMonth()];
var year = date.getFullYear();

var todaysDate = document.getElementById("dateHere").innerHTML = month + "/" + currentDate + "/" + year;
}
```

I expected the date to be presented onto the page as mm/dd/yyyy but nothing is being shown. I even checked the console but I don't see an error being presented. Am I missing something?

Comment: `<text>` is not an HTML tag.  Probably you want `<span>`.

Comment: Also make sure that your `theDate()` function is actually being called.

Comment: Do you have any desire to present the date in the format that the person seeing it expects, for viewers outside the USA?

Comment: Assumption is that the script is running before `document.ready` and it can't find `#dateHere`

Comment: @AndrewMorton No, this is just a personal project of mine

Comment: @Pointy I've used <text> before and I've had no problems with it. I've also changed text to span to see if that would work but nothing happened.

Comment: @Pointy I can't figure out how to join the function together though. Is there some keyword I need to know to connect the function with that? But even then, shouldn't the code know that this line of text is going to connect with the ID of where I'd want it to go?

Comment: If you don't explicitly call a JavaScript function, it will do nothing at all.

Comment: You *could* just use `<p>Today's Date: <script>document.write((new Date()).toLocaleDateString("en-US"))</script></p>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same thing using the `toLocaleDateString()` function like this

```
let date = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-US');
```

The 'en-US' option returns the same format mm/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 1):

You must call the function `theDate` at the beginning of the JavaScript, like this:

```
theDate();

function theDate() {
    var date = new Date();
    var months = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
    var currentDate = date.getDate();
    var month = months[date.getMonth()];
    var year = date.getFullYear();

    var todaysDate = document.getElementById("dateHere").innerHTML = month + "/" + 
currentDate + "/" + year;
}
```

Don't forget to call the JavaScript file in the `body` of your `html`, like this:

```
<body>
    <p>Today's Date:</p><text id="dateHere"></text>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: For neatness, and predictable results, the function should be called after the page has loaded rather than synchronously via a page level event such as onload.

Answer (score 0):

**First** : You need to check if You Html file is linked in with your JS file

**Second** : Be Sure that you have Call You function theDate() to work

---

**Best Practice**: since you don't do anything with the variable todaysDate  just remove it and put you logic as normal line in you code since you don't need todaysDate somewhere else later in your code don't declatre a variable to hold it

Answer (score 0):

Your function return the time as per your format and i guess the issue is with the way its inserted to the id

```
<html>
<body>
    <p>Today's Date:</p><span id="dateHere"></span>
<script>    
function theDate() {
var date = new Date();
var currentDate = date.getDate();
var month = months[date.getMonth()];
var year = date.getFullYear();

var todaysDate = document.getElementById("dateHere").innerHTML = month + "/" + currentDate + "/" + year;
}
theDate() 
</script>
</html>
```